# How do you add click event to element that is returned by backend in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some raw html that is returned in an array from the backend.   (Each line is an element in the array)

For example:

```
 [
     "<button>123</button>",
     "<button>456</button>"
 ]
```

How do I add a click event to all these buttons?  Ideally what I want is a click event that alerts 123 if clicked or 456 if second row is clicked and so on.

I'm stuck understanding how to add these events after the fact?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Render the html into react containers using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), and add the click handler to the container. Now you can use standard dom properties selectors.properties to get the content of the original markup:

```js
const createMarkup = (__html) => ({ dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html }})

const Demo = ({ items }) => {
  const clickHandler = e => console.log(e.currentTarget.firstChild.innerText)

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(html => 
        <div 
          {...createMarkup(html)}
          className="buttonContainer"
          key={html} 
          onClick={clickHandler} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

const html = [
 "<button>123</button>",
 "<button>456</button>"
]

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo items={html} />)
```

```css
.buttonContainer {
  width: fit-content;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If you have a markup that contains multiple elements, attach one click handler to the parent container, and use DOM selectors to get the requested item from the event's target:

```js
const createMarkup = (__html) => ({ dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html }})

const Demo = ({ items }) => {
  const clickHandler = e => {
    const el = e.target.closest('button') // find the click button
    
    if(el) console.log(el.innerText) // if a button inside the container was clicked show it's text
  }
    

  return (
    <div onClick={clickHandler}>
      {items.map(html => 
        <div 
          {...createMarkup(html)}
          key={html} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

const html = ["<div><div><div><button>123</button></div></div></div>"]

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo items={html} />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  One thing I missed is how could this be achieved if button is a part of a broader html markup thats sent back and I want to still target all buttons?  For example: `<div><div><div><button></button></div></div></div>`